# Filtering in Telerik Radgrid

Tags: telerik, filtering, radgrid

We use Telerik Radgrid for the application we create. Whenever we click on Radgrid's filter button on each column, it opens up a new popup like window to select the filter options.
We have made some changes like, displaying all the rows of column selected in that window.

But the issue is, only limited number of rows is loaded in that window, and not all. Can someone help me out of this, please?

Thanks
Manikandan

Comment: Can someone help me get some idea? Please let me know, if i am not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `FilterTemplate` .

```
 <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" FilterControlAltText="Filter Namecolumn"
                HeaderText="Name" UniqueName="Name">
                <FilterTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcboName" DataSourceID="sqlNameDataSource" DataTextField="Name"
                        DataValueField="Name" AppendDataBoundItems="true" SelectedValue='<%# ((GridItem)Container).OwnerTableView.GetColumn("Name").CurrentFilterValue %>'
                        runat="server" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="NameIndexChange" Width="100px">
                        <Items>
                            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="All" />
                        </Items>
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                    <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock2" runat="server">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function NameIndexChange(sender, args) {
                                var tableView = $find("<%# ((GridItem)Container).OwnerTableView.ClientID %>");
                                tableView.filter("Name", args.get_item().get_value(), "EqualTo");
                            }
                        </script>
                    </telerik:RadScriptBlock>
                </FilterTemplate>
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

In my example , I use `sqlNameDataSource` for combobox's datasource .

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlNameDataSource" runat="server"   
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM NameTable">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

You can change this datasource and datafield of your table !

Comment: Before that, i have a doubt in the filter function. Is there any limitation in number of rows displayed, when i click on the filter button?

Comment: I don't  exactly  understand what you say :) But I can say that , after filtering , your gridview's rows will show which are exactly same with your filter value because I use `EqualTo` parameter here ! If you want to change value of filter combobox , you just need to change SelectCommand of `sqlDataSource` .

Comment: I mean, when we click filter button over the column header, we get a window to select the options to filter. In that option selector window, we display the same number of rows which is in the grid. My doubt is, is there any restriction on number of rows being displayed in that filter options window?

Comment: In my example , it's depend on `sqlDataSource` . I suggest you should select your table data with `DISTINCT` value .